# JavaScript filter does not update the React local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Description of the app

I am using [Ant-transfer](https://ant.design/components/transfer/#components-transfer-demo-advanced) for my app. I have two components one is the parent and another is child component. In the child component, I am using the [Ant-transfer](https://ant.design/components/transfer/#components-transfer-demo-advanced), Without fetching any data when I play with local state, I can able to transfer the data from one table to another table. And it works as expected.

### My case scenario is

I have one fixed data. Which contains arrays of objects. From that fixed data, I transfer item from the group table to the target table By using [Ant-transfer](https://ant.design/components/transfer/#components-transfer-demo-advanced). After pressing the transfer button(">") which is then called on `handleChange` function. After triggering the `handleChange` function, it updates the `targetKey` local state and does post request.

### Issue

When an item or items are selected and a post request is made, I retrieve the selected items from the parent component. I filtered the fixed data from the selected items and passed the string id of the items array to the local state. However, when I refresh the page, the fixed data returns to its original state. All items are in the group table, and it does not show select items which should be on the right side of the table. **It appears that my filtered function does not work**.

### Goal:

**My goal is for selected items to be on the right side and unselected items to be on the left side; if I refresh the page, it should not change.**

### Reproduce the ant transfer

I reproduced [Ant-transfer-demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/one-way-antd-4-18-5-forked-b87bz?file=/index.js).

### This is my all code

```
const ZoneGroups: React.FC<Props> = ({
  onAddToZone,
  selectedDisplayGroups,
}) => {
  const displayGroups = [
    {
      id: "FF",
      level: 2,
      name: "rice",
    },
    {
      id: "AA",
      level: 2,
      name: "juice",
    },
    {
      id: "GAA",
      level: 2,
      name: "ball",
    },
    {
      id: "FF3AA",
      level: 2,
      name: "TV",
    },
    {
      id: "FH",
      level: 2,
      name: "Pencil",
    },
    {
      id: "FHAA",
      level: 2,
      name: "Tea",
    },
  ];

  // After post request I am getting updated selected group "selectedDisplayGroups"
  // "selectedDisplayGroups" data array of object like this: 
  // [{
   //   id: "FHAA",
    //  level: 2,
    //  name: "Tea",
  //    }],

  
  const DisplayItems = displayGroups.map((displayGroup, index) => {
    return {
      key: displayGroup.id,
      title: `${displayGroup.level} ${displayGroup.name}`,
    };
  });
  
  
  const SelectedItems = selectedDisplayGroups.map(
    (displayGroup) => displayGroup.id
  );
  // This is the items id which is selected.
  // SelectedItems return array of string ID ['FH', 'FHAA', 'GA'] like this

  const filteredGroups = DisplayItems.filter((g) =>
    SelectedItems.includes(g.key)
  ).map((id) => id.key);

  console.log(SelectedItems);

  const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = useState([]);
  const [targetKey, setTargetKey] = useState(filteredGroups);
  const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (target: string): void => {
    setTargetKey(target);
    onAddToZone(target); // this is my post request function
    setSubmit(true);
  };

  const handleSelectChange = (sourceSelectedKeys: string, id: string): void => {
    setSelectedIds([...sourceSelectedKeys]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Transfer
        dataSource={DisplayItems}
        titles={["Group", "Target"]}
        render={(item): string => item.title}
        targetKeys={targetKey}
        selectedKeys={selectedIds}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onSelectChange={handleSelectChange}
        showSearch
        oneWay
        checked={submit}
        style={{ marginBottom: 50 }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ZoneGroups;
```

Comment: If you want your state to persist through a page reload, i.e. your entire app is remounted, then you need to persist the state to longer term and less volatile system, like localStorage. Persist to localStorage after state updates, initialize your state from localStorage when the app/component mounts.

Comment: To persist your state even after refresh you need to use localStorage, once you have API that updates and on refresh updated API fetches data than you can remove localStorage.

Comment: But I am getting the selected items from database. then I filtered with my display-group which. It's a raw data not temporary data. Why do I need localstorage for this.

Comment: I think my brain is blank. Can you guys please show me as a code 

Comment: I don't understand what that codesandbox is supposed to reproduce, unless it's simply that act of reloading the page and seeing the app remount and all the state reset. Where are you getting any data externally? Everything in your CSB is hardcoded. LocalStorage is used to persist any local component/app state so when the app is reloaded it can be correctly initialized.

Comment: Oh yeah, Now I get it.

Comment: Now question is which value I should save in localstorage?

Comment: Sir Drew, Thank you for sticking with me. Now question is which value I should save it to the localstorage. https://codesandbox.io/s/one-way-antd-4-18-5-forked-b87bz?file=/index.js

Comment: Because both displayGroups and selectedDisplayGroups, I am getting from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to persist any of the state to localStorage to allow reloading the  app then it appears you should persist the `targetKeys` state.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  // Lazy state initializer function to load from localStorage
  // or fallback/default initial value
  const [targetKeys, settargetKeys] = useState(() => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("targetKeys")) || filteredGroups;
  });
  const [selectedKeys, setselectedKeys] = useState([]);

  // persist state updates to localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("targetKeys", JSON.stringify(targetKeys));
  }, [targetKeys]);

  const handleChange = (nextTargetKeys) => {
    settargetKeys(nextTargetKeys);
  };

  const handleSelectChange = (sourceSelectedKeys) => {
    setselectedKeys([...sourceSelectedKeys]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Transfer
        dataSource={DisplayItems}
        titles={["Source", "Target"]}
        targetKeys={targetKeys}
        selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onSelectChange={handleSelectChange}
        render={(item) => item.title}
        oneWay
        style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit javascript-filter-does-not-update-the-react-local-state]

When the component mounts you'll very likely want to refetch any data from your DBs to ensure you've the latest backend data, but if you needed any of this data at app start/mount then persist any other data/state your app/component needs.